# c# "return" does not terminate the Button Clicked event and triggers Timer

Tags: c#, timer, return

Sorry if this question is too elementary.  I am trying to sort of replicate matching game tutorial

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553234.aspx

But I am using customized buttons (named Cards)to show images.  A Card has two images (back, front).  Back is identical for all Cards, "front" is the image of the randomly assigned picture.  Setting image to back hides the random image and front reveals it.  If two consecutively clicked have the same kind of Image (match) I want the click event to end without triggering timer, but it seems that the timer is triggered anyway.  Here is code in button Click event.  I tried using firstClicked.front instead of firstClicked.Image in the if() but nothing seems to work.  Thanks

```
private void card_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            return;

        Card clickedCard = sender as Card;


        if (clickedCard != null) 
        {

            if (clickedCard.Image == clickedCard.front) //ingore Clicks on already revealed cared
                return;



            if (firstClicked == null)
            {
                firstClicked = clickedCard;
                firstClicked.Image = firstClicked.front;

                return;
            }
            //Clicked card is second card

            secondClicked = clickedCard;
            secondClicked.Image = secondClicked.front;



            if (firstClicked.Image == secondClicked.Image)
            {
                firstClicked = null;
                secondClicked = null;
                    return;
            }


            timer1.Start();

        }
 }
```

Comment: Debug your code. Do you enter the last if?

Comment: Where does the debugger say it failed ?

Comment: First never use == true or == false. Also do you know how returns work ? They exit the method that they are in. Effectively stopping everything after them in that method from running. Currently if timer1 is enabled then nothing else will run.

Comment: @deathismyfriend: "Never use == true or == false"? Why not? It's a style thing. There's nothing wrong with a little redundancy. It's on the order of using braces to enclose a single statement.

Comment: @JimMischel I think it comes from seeing people also write `myBool != false`

Comment: @jim mischel. That is incorrect. Using ==true or ==false causes another operation to be performed. Basically it checks if timer1.enabled then it checks to see if the Boolean is equal to true. If it gets inlined that is fine but when debugging it is slower. Using braces is different. The braces are syntax. That is compiled out.

Comment: @deathismyfriend: You should write some test code, compile it, and view the generated IL. You will find that the code generated for `if (timer1.Enabled == true)` is identical to that generated for `if (timer1.Enabled)`, and the code generated for `if (timer1.Enabled == false)` is the same as for `if (!timer1.Enabled)`.

Comment: That is interesting. I wonder if it is because of the new update for visual studio. Last time I tested that it did compile it differently. I'll have to look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve It doesn't get into the if bracket even when the image in the first card and the image are the same. The images are selected from a list that contains each image twice.  Do you think that matters?  It works in the case of a string.

Comment: @Greg.  It does not fail.  It just triggers the timer both when the images are the same and the images are different.

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with the way you're assigning images. Show the code that assigns images to the front and back of the cards. My suspicion is that what you think are equal images really aren't equal images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adrian.  As you said I realize I was comparing the objects and not the images.  I included id to buttons so that two images with similar image have identical ids.  Then instead of comparing the images, I used id's and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `clickedCard.Image` is of type`System.Drawing.Image` in which case comparing images by using `clickedCard.Image == clickedCard.front` will simply not work. This is because this operation will not be actually comparing the content of the images but instead the objects which represent them. In C#, there are different ways of comparing an object which you can read more about in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and) which explains comparing objects in more detail than what the tutorial you're using does.

Comparing two images is actually a bit complex and can actually be expensive to compute if you do it incorrectly. This is why the matching game tutorial is comparing string values instead of Images since it is easier and cheaper to compute. Since you're pretty new to programming, I would probably stick to the tutorial's method until you've reached a more advanced level.

**Edit:** I just wanted to clarify what I meant by my last sentence. Experimenting is a good thing as it is a great way of learning new things. What you're attempting to do however will probably require learn some intermediate steps before you attempt to tackle the issue.